# Image icon is not displayed inside text field when auto complete is enabled in the browser

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

This is my code. I inserted a icon inside the text field at the left. When auto complete feature is enabled in the browser, image getting disappeared by the autocomplete. What should i do, to make the icon displayed even when the autocomplete feature is enabled inside the browser ?

```
 input.usernm{
                  font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;
                  text-indent: 8px;text-transform: uppercase;height: 10px;background: url(resources/images/userimg.png) no-repeat 8px 7px;width: 183px;
              } 


<h:inputText styleClass="usernm" style="color:black;font-weight: bold" id="username" maxlength="8" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter a username" value="#{userBean.username}"/>
```