# icons gone in text field when form auto filled

Tags: css

[image]

[image]

When the form is ***auto-filled***, the icon is gone, and how can I fix that?
Someone asked similar question, but was never answered. [A forgotton question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641505/image-icon-is-not-displayed-inside-text-field-when-auto-complete-is-enabled-in-t)

CSS:

```
input[type=text] {
 width: 200px;
 height: 25px;
 padding: 0;
 border: solid 1px;
}

#name {
 background: url(images/icons/user.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size: 20px 20px;
 background-position: 5px;
 padding-left: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Code http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: have noticed there's different backgrounds ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community.  As mentioned before, please include a [mcve] to your question. Without it, it is nearly impossible to know *exactly* where the issue lies.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you guys mean...

Comment: We mean that, without a complete example, it is hard to see why the code behaves the way it does.  For example, we do not see your HTML.  Is there any JavaScript involved?, etc.  Providing a [mcve] will not only reproduce the issue but give enough details to others to start troubleshooting.  Without that, we are just guessing at what *could* be causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, This problem happens because the browser auto-filling changes the background color to yellow and I think there are no way to override this auto-filling because you use background-image, we just can override the background-color like that:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
```

But we have some things to do :

1- you can use `autocomplete="off"` to prevent auto complete and we can avoid this problem.

2- you can give the background image to another element like using :before for the div which contain the input element, I made demo for this solution and you can see it here : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/obc68xhw/

HTML:

```
<div class="inputContainer">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

and the style :

```
input[type=text] {
 width: 200px;
 height: 25px;
 padding: 0;
 border: solid 1px;
 background:white;
 padding-left: 25px;
}

input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}

.inputContainer{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

.inputContainer:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  top:3px;
  left:5px;
  background: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/male-user-shadow_318-34042.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}
```